# How can i force gatling to print the request body in the scala file?

Tags: gatling

By default the  Gatling recorder seems to put the request body in a seperate folder and then refer to the  file in the scala program, however, I have a requirement where I need to correlate and parameterize few variables in the request body. How can I accomplish this in Gatling?

Actual

```
 .....body(RawFileBody("QBOLogin3_0057_request.txt")), ....
```

to

```
 .....body(StringBody("A very long request body...")), ....
```

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem. Did you ever find a solution to this?